# Regex: pattern based on previous capture group

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following Regex pattern:

```
(A|B|C)stuffinbetween(D|E|F)
```

Is there a way to match only the following patterns:

```
AstuffinbetweenD
BstuffinbetweenE
CstuffinbetweenF
```

?

(I want to match it without having to specify the fully unrolled Regex 3 times for 3 patterns...)

Comment: That seems be matching all the 3 strings, right? May be i am missing something?

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate language that you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your regex flavor supports it you can use [**conditionals**](http://regular-expressions.mobi/conditional.html) like this:

```
(?:(A)|(B)|C)stuffinbetween(?(1)D|(?(2)E|F))
```

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3a(A)%7c(B)%7cC)stuffinbetween(%3f(1)D%7c(%3f(2)E%7cF))&i=AstuffinbetweenD%0d%0aBstuffinbetweenE%0d%0aCstuffinbetweenF%0d%0aCstuffinbetweenE)

`(?(1)true|false)`: if group 1 is defined then "true" else "false"

**To make the pattern more efficient**

with PCRE, you can use the S modifier that can improve alternations:

```
~(?:(A)|(B)|C)stuffinbetween(?(1)D|(?(2)E|F))~S
```

always with PCRE or Perl, you can use the `(*SKIP)` control verb to skip already tested letters (only if "stuffinbetween" doesn't contain A, B, or C):

```
~(?=[ABC])(?:(A)|(B)|C)stuffinbetween(*SKIP)(?(1)D|(?(2)E|F))~
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY0cY2/1)

With other flavors, you can start the pattern with a lookahead to quickly discards useless positions in the string:

```
(?=[ABC])(?:(A)|(B)|C)stuffinbetween(?(1)D|(?(2)E|F))
```

Comment: I think lookahead-based restriction is more effecient than conditional regex. At least testing at regex101 shows lookaheads are more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that without *restricting* the pattern.

Pattern restriction is achieved with *lookarounds*.

So, either use lookaheads (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xK5dO2/2)):

```
(A(?=stuffinbetweenD)|B(?=stuffinbetweenE)|C(?=stuffinbetweenF))stuffinbetween(D|E|F)
```

Or lookbehinds:

```
(A|B|C)stuffinbetween((?<=Astuffinbetween)D|(?<=Bstuffinbetween)E|(?<=Cstuffinbetween)F)
```

Note that for the second method to work with patterns of undefined length you need a regex flavor that supports them (.NET, Pypi regex Python module, JG Soft).

Comment: Note that conditional expression suggested by Casimir et Hyppolyte is perhaps more readable and will work with PCRE/.NET, a lookahead solution is more efficient and will work  with the majority of regex flavors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can!

```
(?:A(stuffinbetween)D|B\g<1>E|C\g<1>F)
```

It is because `\g<1> recurses the 1st subpattern`.

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/eD4mR5/1)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I believe OP uses .NET. At least almost all OP previous regex questions are for .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could use:

```
String g1 = "stuffinbetween";
String regex = "(?:A" + g1 + "D|B" + g1 + "E|C" + g1 + "F)";
```

:p